# Limit the number of exited containers on a host (1.8.3)

Tags: docker

Is there a way to limit the number of exited containers on a host in general or (ideally) to specific images?

I have a cron job that runs daily to removed them but I'd like docker to handle it, if possible.

I can't just have the cron job run more often because developers like a few old copies of a container to check.

Comment: You can launch your containers with `docker run --rm` if it applies  for your environment, so that they disappear automagically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker does not support a limit for the number of exited containers. In fact, Docker does not support any form of garbage collection for stopped containers. However, there are third-party tools such as [docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc) that support garbage collection of old containers and unused images. However, docker-gc does not support a limit for the number of stopped containers as you requested.

If you want to write a script that solves your problem: `docker inspect` gives you a `FinishedAt` date for stopped containers. You can list all containers with a specific image, sort them by the finish date, and then remove all images that exceed your limit. The python module [`docker-py`](http://docker-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/) might be useful for that.